# Self signed certificate in local network does not work any more after browser update

Tags: ssl, certificate, localhost, self-signed

I have a website on our Internal network that uses self signed certificate. After chrome update users started to see message about website being insecure.
Is there any way how the problem could be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using local CA. [Domain Server Certificate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731014(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is based on a recent change in Chrome (and also Firefox) which warns on certificates which are signed with the (insecure) MD5 algorithm (see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101123) OR are signed with SHA1 and are valid for more than 2 years (from now).

Certificates should be at least signed by SHA1 or even better SHA256 (to avoid problems in the near future, see http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.de/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html).